# Execution order when dynamically injecting script elements

Tags: javascript, dom-events

When I dynamically inject a `<script>` element into a page using Javascript, and I specify an `onload` event handler, which executes first, the script that is downloaded by the injected element, or the `onload` event handler?

E.g.

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "http://example.com/foo.js";
script.async = true;
script.onload = function() {
    console.log("foo.js is loaded");
};
document.getElementByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out, according to [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#script), that the script executes before the onload event assigned to that `<script>` element.

Here's the relevant quote, emphasis mine:

> 4. Create a script, using the script block's source, the URL from which the script was obtained, the script block's type as the scripting language, and the script settings object of the script element's Document's Window object.
>
>    If the script came from a resource that was fetched in the steps above, and the resource was CORS-cross-origin, then pass the muted errors flag to the create a script algorithm as well.
>
>    **This is where the script is compiled and actually executed.**
> 5. Decrement the ignore-destructive-writes counter of neutralized doc, if it was incremented in the earlier step.
> 6. Fire a simple event named afterscriptexecute that bubbles (but is not cancelable) at the script element.
> 7. If the script is from an external file, fire a simple event named load at the script element.
>
>    Otherwise, the script is internal; queue a task to fire a **simple event named load** at the script element.

Answer (score -1):

I think you probably want to look into flux or redux and React.js. Redux and flux allows you to dispatch data after fetch from a source without adding whole bunch event listener. Add plus emitting data without these frameworks is a pain.